# Can I use NAnt to query my database and use the results as parameter values?

Tags: database, email, nant

I spent 15 minutes searching the Task lists of NAnt and NAntContrib, and searching Google, but came up empty-handed.

I want to send an email to every user of my system when I promote my code.  I have a list of email addresses in my database, and I have a functioning email task.  So, how can I connect the two?

Thanks!
D

---

When I get time to return to this, I think I will issue a select statement via sqlcmd.exe, saving the results (a list of email addresses) to a text-file. I will then read the contents of the text file, and use the values therein to address my emails. Seems like a hack -- please tell me there's something more elegant....?

Comment: When I get time to return to this, I think I will issue a select statement via sqlcmd.exe, saving the results (a list of email addresses) to a text-file.  I will then read the contents of the text file, and use the values therein to address my emails.  Seems like a hack -- please tell me there's something more elegant....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<target name="uat.notify">
    <exec program="${sqlcmd.exe}" commandline='-S DB_SERVER -b -o email.txt -Q "set nocount on;use DATABASE;select email_address from dbo.t_users" -h -1' />
    <foreach item="Line" in="email.txt" property="email.address">
        <if test="${string::get-length(string::trim(email.address)) > 0}" >
            <mail failonerror="false" 
                from="SENDER@DOMAIN.com" 
                tolist="${string::trim(email.address)}"
                format="Html"
                subject="test:notify"
                mailhost="MAILHOST"
            >
                <files>
                    <include name="notify.htm" />
                </files>
            </mail>
        </if>
    </foreach>
</target>
```

Comment: Cheers for posting this, this is very similar to what I need to do :)